# Calculating a Rolling Quarter to Date

Tags: sql, row-number

I am trying to calculate “quarter to date” values for each fiscal year. The main fields in my data set can be summarized as:

Customer ID, Service Start Date, Service End Date, Service Level

I have a function which when cross multiply the start and end date fields, creates a record for each month. Note, my fiscal year starts April.
So my table looks something like:

```
Customer ID, Service Start Date, Service End Date, Service Level, Fiscal Year, Fiscal Quarter, Fiscal Month Start
12345, Jan 1, 2019, Apr 30, 2019, 93, Q4, Jan 2019
12345, Jan 1, 2019, Apr 30, 2019, 93, Q4, Feb 2019
12345, Jan 1, 2019, Apr 30, 2019, 93, Q4, Mar 2019
12345, Jan 1, 2019, Apr 30, 2019, 93, Q1, Apr 2019
```

What I am struggling with is that I want to count a unique quarter to date for the HIGHEST Service level of a customer within a fiscal year. So we want to group each fiscal year with that customer's highest service level.

So for example: 
If customer started service with service level 93 in November 2018
And customer ended service with service level 94 in May 2019

If this hypothetical patient switched service levels during FY 1819 I want to be able to get a final quarter to date within a fiscal year count of:
Q3 2018: 1 for SRC 94
Q4 2018: 2 for SRC 94
Q1 2019: 1 for SRC 94
Q2 2019: 1 for SRC 94
Q3 2019: 1 for SRC 94

But if they switched service level in April 2019 (which is a different fiscal year) my counts would be

```
Q3 2018: 1 for SRC 93
Q4 2018: 2 for SRC 93
Q1 2019: 1 for SRC 94
Q2 2019: 1 for SRC 94
Q3 2019: 1 for SRC 94
```

What I have gotten so far, is a “unique count” per patient per quarter using the row_number function:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_ID, FISCALYEAR, Fiscalquarterstartdate ORDER BY fiscalmonthstartdate DESC) PtRnk
into #Temp
```

And then I would select all the records that have ptRnk = 1, and then sum that ptrnk field up.

I am kind of struggling though how to deal with the condition I have outlined above. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of rows for each group of [quarter, highest service level,patient]?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Pretty much I want to count the unique patients FYTD in each quarter. For example, if a customer received services in 3 quarters they should be counted as 3 in the last quarter for that fiscal year

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the highest service level and then do a simple group by:

**untested**

```
select T1.Customer_ID, T1.Fiscal_Quarter, T1.Fiscal_Year,
   count(*) Services_Received, T2.Service_Level
from YourTable T1
inner join (
   select Customer_ID, Fiscal_Year, max(Service_Level) Service_Level
   from YourTable
   group by Customer_ID, Fiscal_Year
) T2
   on T1.Customer_ID = T2.Customer_ID
   and T1.Fiscal_Year = T2.Fiscal_Year
group by T1.Customer_ID, T1.Fiscal_Quarter, T1.Fiscal_Year, T2.Service_Level
```